# Apple Push Notification listening port on iPhone

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, port

I am trying to determine when the iOS receives a push notification and want to listen on the port. The App being worked on is "always on" in the background (LBS app), therefore it would be very nice to use the APN service to send requests to the app when in the background without requiring the user to click View.

Does anyone know what the incoming port is for the push service on the iPhone?

Answer (score 4):

Push Notification is TCP 5223.

See: [Important Apple Ports](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1629)

[Apple Push Notification Support](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3576)